# Set jnlp resource as a "dependency"

Tags: dependencies, java-web-start, jnlp

Hi!

Is there anyway to include non jar files to my dependency list in jnlp? By dependency i mean a way to make my code look for these non jar files as a "dependency".

When my code looks for for a set of database files I want to specify in jnlp where it should look for it. Like a system property I would think be the best name ?

Is it possible to specify this in my maven plugin for java webstart?

Thanks!

Comment: What would you _not_ use a JAR?

Comment: U mean that i bundle my resources in a jar and accessing and then use it as a dependency? In that case, will jnlp look for my files in my dependency list before looking for them in my user.dir?
I just want jnlp to look for my files in my dependency list before looking for them somewhere else :)

Comment: It's up to your application to manage this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in [`<resources>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources), "The resources element has six different possible subelements: jar, nativelib, j2se, property, package, and extension." A compressed JAR is the correct container for miscellaneous dependencies. As described in [*Retrieving Resources from JAR files*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/development.html#retrieving), "Java Web Start only transfers JAR files from the Web server to the client machine." It's up to your application to provide the mechanisms to manage working copies in user-accessible storage.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i think it is a bit overkill to make my setting files to a jar. Its better to specify a catalog in user.home to look for.